# Gnome3 Authentication Popups take over screen

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm running into an issue on a box I do not have root on.  Something running is prompting me to authenticate, but I don't care about what its doing.  The dialog window takes over the entire Gnome3 shell, i can't minimize it or use any other program.  Instead i have to hit cancel 17 times to finally make the dialog go away.

Is there a way to tell gnome to not let dialogs like that take over the session?  I want to be able to just minimize and ignore it, so that i don't have to sit there and hit cancel a million times.

The "attach modal" setting doesn't do it, since that applies to applications and not the root shell (i'm guessing).

[Screenshot of undesired dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqwMn.png)

Comment: Would be good to provide more details on the nature of the dialog, and eventually post a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, edited and added screenshot.